# Find maximum and minimum value by lagrange multiplier method

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the maximum and minimum values of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ subject to the equality constraints $x + y + z = 1$ and $x y z + 1 = 0$

My try:

Let $u=x^2+y^2+z^2$
     $$x+y+z-1=0$$
     $$xyz+1=0$$
$$(xdx+ydy+zdz)+m(dx+dy+dz)+n(yzdx+xzdy+xydz)=0$$
$$x+m+yzn=0$$
$$y+m+xzn=0$$
$$z+m+xyn=0$$

Multiplying by $x ,y$ and $z$ then adding above three equations i get
$u+m+n=0.¢
What should i do after that.. please help me.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you eliminate some variables?

Comment: The symmetry of the variables in all three functions suggests that one should look for solutions with $x=y$, $y=z$ and/or $z=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $x,y,z$ are the roots of a monic, cubic polynomial in the $t$-variable, 
$$ q(t) = t^3-t^2+ct+1. $$
This polynomial has three real roots iff its discriminant is non-negative, i.e. iff
$$ 4c^3-c^2+18c+23\leq 0.$$
We want maximize/minimize $x^2+y^2+z^2 = (x+y+z)^2-2c = 1-2c$ over the previous constraint, but the polynomial $4c^3-c^2+18c+23$ has a unique real root at $c=-1$. It follows that under the constraints $x+y+z=1$ and $xyz=-1$ the quantity $x^2+y^2+z^2$ can take any value $\geq 3$, which is attained at the cyclic permutations of $(1,1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With $$z=1-x-y$$ we get
$$x^2+y^2+(1-x-y)^2$$ and the equation $$xy-x^2y-xy^2+1=0$$
Now you can eliminate $x$ or $y$, and you will get a problem in one variable only.